# Why appear ClassCast exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm building sandbox project with simple microservices where I have Eureka service, gateway service and one more service which needs to use websockets.
here is config of gateway:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.iauto</groupId>
    <artifactId>apigateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apigateway</name>
    <description>gateway for requests services</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and properties file:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lowerCaseServiceId: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Here is configs of websocket-based microservice:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.iauto</groupId>
    <artifactId>requests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>requests</name>
    <description>requests service with client offers and chats</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WebSocket Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

app props:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8082
  error:
    includeBindingErrors: always
    include-message: always

spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: requests-service
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

here are websockets and route configs:

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("requests-service", r -> r.path("/api/v1/**")
                        .uri("lb://requests-service"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
import com.iauto.requests.controller.WebSocketMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/api/v1/request_chat/{sessionId}/{clientId}")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
        return new WebSocketMessageHandler();
    }
}
```

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.iauto.requests.dto.RequestDTO;
import com.iauto.requests.entity.ChatSession;
import com.iauto.requests.service.RequestService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;


@Controller
public class WebSocketMessageHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private RequestService requestService;
    private Map<String, ChatSession> chatSessions;

    public WebSocketMessageHandler(RequestService requestService) {
        this.requestService = requestService;
        this.chatSessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public WebSocketMessageHandler() {}

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        // Handle incoming WebSocket messages
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RequestDTO requestDTO = objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload(), RequestDTO.class);

        String path = session.getUri().getPath();
        String[] pathSegments = path.split("/");
        String sessionId = pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 2];
        String clientId = pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 1];

        requestDTO.setSessionId(sessionId);
        requestDTO.setClientId(clientId);

        RequestDTO savedRequestDTO = requestService.processMessage(requestDTO);

        ChatSession chatSession = chatSessions.computeIfAbsent(sessionId, ChatSession::new);
        chatSession.broadcast(savedRequestDTO);
    }
}
```

When I try to send message to: `ws://localhost:8080/requests-service/api/v1/request_chat/1/1`

In gateway service I get:

```
WebSocketClientHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 500
```

in requests-service I get error:

```
ClassCastException: class org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade cannot be cast to class reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse (org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade and reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.server.upgrade.ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.upgrade(ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.java:163) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException
```

How this error can be fixed? It seems like I have both approaches in application - reactive and non-reactive and they conflict with each other, but I'm confused and this is unclear.

UPDATE: I probably understood, where is the problem. If I comment line `web-application-type: reactive` , then service fails to start with error: `Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway`
I checked dependencies and found out, that `spring-boot-starter-websocket` dependency relies on `spring-boot-starter-web`. when flag 'reactive' is active this cause that `ClassCastException` problem. And here I dont know how to proceed - I need cloed and websockets in my app

Comment: you should add the `import`s of your Java code snippet - maybe you have some wrong imports there for classes of the same basename?

Comment: @cyberbrain updated question, added imports

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look as if the error is there. But good that we could check it.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the code snippet of WebSocketMessageHandler?

Comment: @cyberbrain I probably found the reason(updated question), but dont know how to proceed. Could you have a look?

Comment: Try excluding dependencies from the websocket dependency that have the class try to be cast.

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian added Handler's code

Comment: @Bohemian excluded starter-web dependency. now I'm getting another error which refers to class not found exception(probably websocket lib cant find some web starter classes)

Comment: If you can produce a dependency graph or similar, you could try to more fine-grained either exclude dependencies OR do not include spring-boot-starter-websocket as a whole, but just those libs it depends on, that you need. You also can check where the `org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade` comes from (it is probably a part of Tomcat) and if you can get rid of it or do some configuration to not use it.

Comment: @sam I didn't mean exclude starter-web. Keep starter-web, but inside that dependency add an `<exclusions>` element to exclude the library being dragged in that has the class being used (you'll have to figure out which library yourself). See [maven exclusion doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#how-to-use-dependency-exclusions) for how to code the XML.